# Querying in django models

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models user and posts. Each post is associated to a user and user can follow each other and the user model contains a field called is_private_profile depending on which user's posts are visible to eveyone or only to those who follow the user.

I want to fetch all the posts whose authors have public profile and the posts for users with private profile only if the user who wants the post follows him

```
class Posts(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_(
       "Author"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="posts")
    caption = models.TextField(_("Caption"))
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
       _("Created At"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(
       _("Updated At"), auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
   email = models.EmailField(_("Email"), max_length=254, unique=True)
   follows = models.ManyToManyField("self", verbose_name=_(
      "Followers"), symmetrical=False, related_name='followed_by')
   is_private_profile = models.BooleanField(
      _("Is Private profile"), default=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the posts whose authors have public profile:

```
Post.objects.filter(author__is_private_profile=False)
```

All the posts whose authors have private profile:

```
Post.objects.filter(author__is_private_profile=True)
```

EDIT:
All posts depending on whether the currently logged in user follows the author or not

```
Post.objects.filter(author__follows=request.user).distinct()
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but what I want is more like all the posts in one query set with all the public posts and private depending on whether the currently logged in user follows the author or not

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. I was under the impression that m2m field is a list so comparing it with user id won't work.